# Ruby inter class communication

Tags: ruby

I met strange difficulty developing one project. I dont have enough experience with classes so this is why I ask here. I have one class which is initialized with one parameter and I need other classes to call that class functions but I cant until that class is initialized so I asking how I could do that.

Here is some example what I talking about:

```
class AVR
    def initialize(device)
        @device = device
        @avr_conf = YAML::load(File.open("./devices/#{device}.yaml"))
    end

    def avr_conf
        return @avr_conf
    end
end

class IO
    def setMode(a,b)
        "#{AVR.avr_conf[a]} = #{b}"
    end
end
```

Comment: There seems to be no easy way here. `AVR` needs a `device` to be initialized, and there's no device in `setMode` method. Do you not show us the full code of `IO` class?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It's just idea but I would like to somehow make Master class after which was initialized every sub class also would be initialized so there would be no missing unloaded classes?

Comment: I feel like the whole class isn't shown. The code above would not even run? Because `class IO`'s `setMode` is trying to run a singleton method on AVR... correct? There must be more to AVR.... a `def self.avr_conf` must be in there somewhere?

Comment: You are monkeypatching the existing [IO class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/IO.html) , don't know if it is intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either: need an instance, or to make `avr_conf` a class method (and initialize differently).

With an instance:

```
avr = AVR.new(a_device)
avr.avr_conf[a]
```

With a config singleton (roughly):

```
class AVR
  def self.class_initialize(device)
    @@avr_conf ... etc ...
  end

  def self.avr_conf
    return @@avr_conf
  end
end
```

Then class `IO` would need to use the updated version, however that's appropriate.

If IO isn't going to/can't get an instance, the class/singleton-config *might* make more sense, although that approach always makes me a little nervous.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the dependent method simply throw an exception if the independent class is not yet initialized:

```
class IO
  def setMode(a, b)
    raise StandardError.new("AVR device is not initialized") unless AVR.avr_conf
    AVR.avr_conf[a] = b
  end
end
```

Note however that this solution requires the AVR class to be a singleton (or module) since the IO extension methods will need to know which instance should be modified.

Comment: In this case, `avr_conf` is an instance method, not a class method, so it's not quite as simple as that. The example seems somewhat confused.

Comment: @tadman: yes, hence the update (which you might not have loaded yet) about instances.

Comment: Ah, I see now. That explains it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of methods in Ruby classes - actually `class` and `instance` methods.
Class methods defines with `self.` prefix and there's no need to initialize class:

```
class AVR
  def self.avr_conf
    'something here'
  end
end
```

So, in this case you must call: `AVR.avr_conf` to get `'something here'` result.

But, in your case, `@avr_conf` variable defines in `initialize` method and you have to create a class instance with:

```
avr = AVR.new('something')
avr.avr_conf[a] = b
```